# Script Runs Fine In Terminal, But Not Under Cron

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron

I'm running this script in terminal and getting desired results, but when I set a `cron` to run it from `/root/somefolder/` every 5 min, it does not do what its supposed to do.

My root user crontab entry looks like this:

```
*/5 * * * * ~root/somedirectory/script.sh
```

The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

## Variables ##
host="`/bin/hostname`";

        ## Limits ##
OneMin="1";
FiveMin="6";
FifteenMin="6";

     ## Mail IDs ##
To="someone@somedomain"; Fr="root@"$host;

     ## Load Averages ##

LA=(`uptime | grep -Eo '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' | cut -d"." -f1`)

      ## Top Process List ##

tp=(`ps -ef | sort -nrk 3,3 | grep -E "(php|httpd)" | grep -v root | head -n30 | awk '{print $2}'`)

## Actions ##

if [ ${LA[0]} -ge $OneMin ]; then

      ## Send Mail ##
echo -e "From: $Fr
To: $To
Subject: *ALERT* - Current Load on '$host' Is High Load Averages Are: \n\n 1:Min\t5:Min\t15:Min \n
${LA[0]}\t${LA[1]}\t${LA[2]} \n\n List Of Processes That Were Killed \n" | sendmail -t

## Kill Top Pocesses ##
for i in $tp ; do kill -9 $i
     done

fi
```

Issues:

1. All the recipients in $To variable don't get any alert, when script is run via cron even the if statement gets true, but when it is run in terminal, everyone gets an email.
2. I tried to paste all email IDs directly in To: fields like this, cause I thought it's not reading $To variable. 
   To: someone@somedomain instead of $To

But still none of the recipients gets any alert, and no actions seems to be performed.

Comment: I suppose space before #!/bin/bash are typos ?

Comment: This is such a long example for a help site. Please try cutting it down to the minimum length that fails (or works). This will help to isolate the problem. One strategy would be to replace the first `if` section with writing to a temporary file instead.

Comment: @Archemar yes typo just here.

Comment: Can you post `crontab` entry that runs this script as well? Is it root user's crontab? Is there anything that could explain the issue in `/var/log/maillog`?

Comment: @yahol yes its root user's cron. Crontab entry is */5 * * * * ~root/somedirectory/script.sh.

Comment: @Sollosa change path to script in crontab to `/root/somedirectory/script.sh`. Root's home is under `/root/`, while regular users under `/home/username/`. `~root/` doesn't make sense, it would rather be `~/somedirectory/script.sh`, but in this case i think it's better to set absolute path.

Comment: @yahol ok I got the reason for the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following syntax for `sendmail` in your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# some code

/usr/sbin/sendmail -t <<EOF
To: noc@example.com "$address1" "$address2"
Cc: support@example.com admin@example.com me@example.com
Subject: [Monitoring] $foo $bar at $host
From: root@example.com

Monitoring for example.com server loss of connectivity - hourly update:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

$some
$more
$variables

EOF
```

You can embed variables in "heredoc" block.

Script name was `monitor.sh`. Entry i used in crontab, as root:

```
@hourly /root/monitor.sh
```

Issues related to `sendmail` or (failed) mail delivery can be checked in `/var/log/maillog`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that shell commands need to be written with an absolute path, so `sendmail` should be `/usr/bin/sendmail`. I updated it and cron started working.

Comment: Uhm... yeah, it kinda is in my answer below...

Comment: @yahol Your answer doesn't actually explain that that's the problem